# Difference between 'by the end of June' and 'at the end of June'

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the difference between 'by the end of June' and 'at the end of June'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*By the end of June* denotes that the end of June is the time at which something has to be done, finished, etc. It evokes a sense that something was happening from before the end of June to the end of June.

> We will have to finish it by the end of June. Else, we will get fired.

*At the end of June* denotes the specific point of time---the end of June. It only talks about that specific point of time.

> At the end of June, I went to Florida.